# Laravel - Segmentation Fault on $app->make()

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Service Provider in Laravel which looks like this:

```
class ImportServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $importable = [
        \MyApp\Agencies\AgencyImporter::class
    ];

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->resolving(Importer::class, function (Importer $importer, $app) {
            foreach($this->importable as $implementation) {
                $importer->attach($app->make($implementation));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The idea being, a number of object can be added as Observers to the `Importer` class when it is instantiated.

However, when I reach this line in the code, I get a `Segmentation Fault` error:

```
$app->make($implementation)
```

However, if I run the code with a hardcoded class before the closure, it works fine:

```
$app->make(\MyApp\Agencies\AgencyImporter::class);

$this->app->resolving(Importer::class, function (Importer $importer, $app) {
       foreach($this->importable as $implementation) {
            //$importer->attach($app->make($implementation));
       }
  });
```

So it seems to be issue with the closure.  Why this happens?

Comment: Do you use PHP 5.x or PHP 7? I had also Segmentation fault a few days ago on PHP 7

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek this is PHP5

Comment: this is problem with PHP7. As you can see, this was fixed in new version 7.0.1 - http://de2.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.0.1

Comment: @psantos im using PHP 5.6

Comment: @dj complete version number? 5.6.x (some php 5.6.x have this bug too)

Comment: @psantos ah i see.  PHP 5.6.16-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1

Comment: @dj http://de2.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.6.16 show that related issue was fixed